# Linear Homogeneous recurrence relations question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Good Day,

Currently I am working with recurrence relations and was given the following:

Given $a_{n+1} = 3a_{n} - 2a_{n-1}$ with initial conditions $a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = 2$.

What is $a_{n}$ expressed as a function of $n$?

I feel rather comfortable with linear homogeneous recurrence relations in the form akin to:

$b_{n} = 3b_{n−1} + 4b_{n−2}$.    Initial values: $b_0 = 4$, $b_1 = 1$.

Where I would take the following steps:

1. Craft Characteristic equation
   $b^2-3b-4$
2. Determine roots (factor)
   $(4,-1)$
3. General Solution :  $b_{n} = \alpha(4^n) + \beta(-1)^n$
4. Plugin initial values (I learned this via using alpha and beta): 
   $b_{0} = 4 = \alpha(4^0) + \beta(-1)^0$ 
   $b_{1} = 1 = \alpha(4^1) + \beta(-1)^1$
5. Solve: $b_{0} = 1$ and $b_{1} = 3$
6. Solution: $b_{n} = 4^n + 3(-1)^n$

Now attempting to follow similar steps with the initial equation given above: $a_{n+1} = 3a_{n} - 2a_{n-1}$ 
I am stumped rather early on by the $a_{n+1}$. I might just be tired and too close to the problem.. I feel this should be rather trivial, but alas my brain is not reaching a breakthrough.

My initial steps were same as above to generate the characteristic equation, taking the smallest term from $a_{n-1}$ and dividing each term by $n-1$. However I get stuck on the $a_{n+1}$ term.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let $b_n=a_{n+1}$. Then the equation becomes $b_n=3b_{n-1}-2b_{n-2}$, and you are on familiar ground.

Comment: Ah marvelous, I think that will do it! Thank you!